# How to set layout_toEndOf and layout_toRightOf programmatically in textview

Tags: android

I want set these attribute programmatically :-

```
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
```

Comment: Use the `addRule()` method on the View's [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The parent of the View has to be a RelativeLayout of course. Then you can do

```
 final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.imageView1);
 params.addRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF, R.id.imageView1);
```

and call

```
view.setLayoutParams(params);
```